# For fedora, how do I get the original text based source file of selinux policy file, as well as plaintext versions of other files, like .te files?

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, selinux

I've been trying to find the original source files for the Fedora selinux policies.

The policy file is distributed as a binary file in the /etc/selinux/targeted/policy. Is there a way to get the original plaintext version of this?

Also, is there a source for .te type enforcement files, it would help greatly with examining the policies used in selinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original source files are located in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy).

Comment: Does this mean there are instructions to compile it and get a bitwise similar file to the fedora policy.33 file?

Comment: Yes, you can fetch source for the `selinux-policy-devel` source RPM and the `.spec` file inside it basically holds the instructions on creating the `selinux-policy` package RPM. Although, I would probably avoid rebuilding the whole policy. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but it's best to create your own selinux module that will work with the global policy.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the online selinux admin guides seem to not go into details of what the different commands do in policies and .if files.